# Running Vert.x (w/ES4X) via Eclipse

Tags: vert.x

This question is a follow-up to:
[Running Vuetify on Vert.x (w/ES4X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795793/running-vuetify-on-vert-x-w-es4x/)

I would like to be able to run ES4X via Eclipse (instead of NPM).  I'm not exactly sure if it's possible or how to wire it in.

Let's say I have the following build.gradle.file

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'application'
  id 'com.johnrengleman.shadow' version "5.0.0"
}
sourceCompatibility='1.8'
mainClassName='io.vertx.core.Launcher'
repositories {
  mavenCentral() 
}
dependencies {
  implementation 'io.vertx:vertx-core:3.7.1'
  implementation 'io.vertx:vertx-web:3.7.1'
  implementation 'io.vertx:vertx-lang-js:3.7.1'
  // implementation 'io.reactiverse:es4x:0.8.0'
  // implementation 'io.reactiverse:es4x-pm:0.8.0'
}
processResources {
  from '/src/main/js'
}
shadowJar {
  classifier = 'fat'
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Verticle' : 'index.js'
  }
  mergeServiceFiles {
    include 'META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory'
  }
}
```

and my src/main/js/index.js looks like the one from the other referenced post:

```
import { Router, StaticHandler } from '@vertx/web';
const app = Router.router(vertx);
app.get().handler(StaticHandler.create("dist"));
vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(app).listen(8080);
```

If I create an executable jar via shadowJar, I get javax.script.ScriptExceptions due to Nashorn choking on the index.js contents (as expected).

If I uncomment the es4x implementation in the gradle build, I get ClassNotFound exceptions for org.graalvm.polyglot.io.FileSystem

So how would I correctly modify this app to take advantage of ES4X?  I guess the equivalent of what the 'es4x init' would do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that you have your `es4x` application and a `package.json`, when you execute:

```
npm install
```

You will get inside `node_modules` a few extra folders:

```
.bin
.lib
```

In the `.bin` directory there is a `es4x-launcher.jar` file you can use to start your application from Eclipse. It will refer to the dependencies which are unpacked to the `.lib` dir. In order to make things work fine the same JVM you have when running the `npm install` command should be used in eclipse. Otherwise you might end up missing dependencies. This is the case when running graalvm which will not require graaljs dependencies or when running on jdk8 which will not require `jvmci` dependencies.

Comment: Hi, thanks!  I'll have to look into it a bit more, but I tried going into the bin directory and running java -jar es4x-launcher.jar via command line and got a 'Failed in deploying verticle caused by ModuleError: Module "./index.js" was not found. I'm assuming that if it can be run in eclipse it could also be run command line

Comment: It turns out I had to execute the jar from the project root vs inside the bin folder.